# How to change value on a specific column in a .dat file | Bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have this .dat file

```
#id|firstName|lastName|gender|birthday|creationDate|locationIP|browserUsed
933|Mahinda|Perera|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
1129|Carmen|Lepland|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
4194|Hồ Chí|Do|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer
8333|Chen|Wang|female|1980-02-02|2010-03-15T10:21:43.365+0000|1.4.16.148|Internet Explorer
```

And i want with an input of an `id` , a `column` and a `value` to change current value of a specific `column` to the new `value` and specify the column from the `id` has given for input.

Example , for command

```
myscript.sh -f datfile.dat --edit 933 3 patrikopoulos
```

I want my file to become

```
#id|firstName|lastName|gender|birthday|creationDate|locationIP|browserUsed
933|Mahinda|patrikopoulos|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
1129|Carmen|Lepland|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
4194|Hồ Chí|Do|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer
8333|Chen|Wang|female|1980-02-02|2010-03-15T10:21:43.365+0000|1.4.16.148|Internet Explorer
```

I am stack somewhere here :

```
if [ "$1" == "-f" ] && [ "$3" == "--edit" ]
then
id="$4"
column="$5"
value="$6"
fi
```

any ideas ?

Comment: I cannot change id value and column must be 2-8. if there isn't the id that user gave then script must finish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk for this:

```
awk -v id=933 -v c=3 -v val='patrikopoulos' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} $1==id{$c = val} 1' file
```

**Output:**

```
#id|firstName|lastName|gender|birthday|creationDate|locationIP|browserUsed
933|Mahinda|patrikopoulos|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
1129|Carmen|Lepland|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
4194|Hồ Chí|Do|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer
8333|Chen|Wang|female|1980-02-02|2010-03-15T10:21:43.365+0000|1.4.16.148|Internet Explorer
```

Comment: And if i want to check for column parameters ?

I cannot change id value and column must be 2-8. if there isn't the id that user gave then script must finish

Comment: @user3583029 And you do not change any id, use your input parameters instead of example values: `awk -v id="$4" -v c="$5" val="$6" ...` for your case will suite

Comment: Yes but doesnt change my file :/

Comment: awk command doesn't change the file. You will need to store the output in a temporary file and move it back like: **`awk -v id=933 -v c=3 -v val='patrikopoulos' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} $1==id{$c = val} 1' file > _file.tmp && mv _file.tmp file`**

Answer (score 1):

With sed :

```
$ id=933; col=3; str="patrikipoulos"
$ sed "/^$id|/s/[^|]*/$str/$col" file
#id|firstName|lastName|gender|birthday|creationDate|locationIP|browserUsed
933|Mahinda|patrikipoulos|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
1129|Carmen|Lepland|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
4194|Hồ Chí|Do|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer
8333|Chen|Wang|female|1980-02-02|2010-03-15T10:21:43.365+0000|1.4.16.148|Internet Explorer
```

If `933` is found in first column, then search `3`rd occurrence of non-pipe characters and replace with `patrikopoulos`.